# Survival competing risk cox model

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am using the `survival` package to do competing risk analysis and would like to use the prediction to do simulation.

I plan to sample a uniform random x from [0, 1], find the termination time from survival curve that intersect with x; and then sample another random y from [0, hazard1 + hazard2] to decide which end state to choose.

I can extract survival curve but don't know what are the hazard for individual competing states. I copied example from Vignettes "compete" of the `survival` package below:

```
data(mgus2)
cfit1 <- coxph(Surv(etime, event=="pcm") ~ age + sex + mspike, mgus2)
etime <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, futime, ptime))
event <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, 2*death, 1))
event <- factor(event, 0:2, labels=c("censor", "pcm", "death"))
cfit2 <- coxph(Surv(etime, event=="death") ~ age + sex + mspike, mgus2)
cfit1 <- coxph(Surv(etime, event=="pcm") ~ age + sex + mspike, mgus2)
newdata <- expand.grid(sex=c("F", "M"), age=c(60, 80), mspike=1.2)
newdata
temp <- matrix(list(), 3,3)
dimnames(temp) <- list(from=c("Entry", "PCM", "Death"),
to =c("Entry", "PCM", "Death"))
temp[1,2] <- list(survfit(cfit1, newdata, std.err=FALSE))
temp[1,3] <- list(survfit(cfit2, newdata, std.err=FALSE))
csurv <- survfit(temp, p0 =c(1,0,0))
```

It looks like `csurv$pstate` contains the survival curve and cumulative hazards. But I don't understand their relationship. I tried to back out survival by adding up the two cumulative hazards and take exp as below but the results are different from survival curve.

```
exp(-(csurv$pstate[,2]+csurv$pstate[,3]))
csurv$pstate[,1]
```

How are they related?  How do I use them for simulation?

Comment: I don't understand your plan for simulation and that part of the question seems more appropriate for CrossValidated.com, anyway, so voting to migrate. Now that I've explained some of the errors in your understanding the `survfit`-object's structure, I think you should expand your paragraph where you describe the simulation strategy and ask if the more patient statisticians can walk you through improving it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed the pstate are probabilities and I don't need  to take exp operation.  I now know how to use pstate to do the simulation.

Comment: I'll post it. and delete my comment as redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says there is a prev component of a survfit object which is the "prevalence in state". (Perhaps Terry forgot to fix the documentation when he change the name?) Since it is a probability, at any given time the sum of probabilities should be 1. And therefore you would not be exponentiating them. When I tabulate the rowSums of pstate component, all the sums (three values per row) are within numerical error of 1.0. So exponentiation of the sums would be equal to `e`, not what you expected. I'd drop the `exp` operation. It's already been done for you "behind the scenes."